# How to make sure that the user did shared site page on the Facebook wall

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, api, social-networking

For example, the user presses the button "Share this page with Facebook". How can I verify that this record/post was created and exists on his Facebook wall?

Comment: Ask user permissions.. You can read his wall posts using API..

Comment: For what purpose? I hope you are aware that you are not allowed to “force” users to share (to get access to a certain piece of content or something like that), and not allowed to “reward” them for sharing either. (If that was your intention, and this is news to you - then it’s high time you go read Facebook’s [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).)